# What documents do I need to travel to Northern Ireland from another part of the UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, northern-ireland

I am a Chinese citizen living in England. I have a PRC passport with a UK visa. I plan to go on holiday to Northern Ireland soon and will travel there by plane. Is there anything I should bring other than my passport in order to be allowed to board the flight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should bring your passport, you don't need anything in addition to this.

Northern Ireland is part of the UK, so it's a domestic trip with no "immigration" or similar.

However, almost all airlines require passengers to have photo ID (for their own commercial reasons - basically to ensure that person flying is the same as the person named on the ticket) and a passport is the best form of photo ID for a non-European citizen to use.

Comment: My recent experience is that if you check in online (which does require identity document numbers), then you won't be required to actually show ID at any point in the process.

Comment: As it turned out from checking the internet, citizens of non-EU/EEA countries need to show their passport at the check-in desk if traveling with Ryanair - not sure if other airlines have similar rules - so it is best to bring one's passport just to be safe.