# Is there passport control when taking the Stena Line ferry from Belfast to Stranraer?

Tags: uk, ferries, northern-ireland

I am a Bulgarian citizen in Northern Ireland and I want to go to Stranraer (Scotland) for my friend's birthday. I have my European Bulgarian national ID card but I do not have my passport. Can I travel or not?

Comment: This may help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64418/what-documents-do-i-need-to-travel-to-northern-ireland-from-another-part-of-the?rq=1 although it is about the rules for flying which are different.

Comment: What is your status in the UK? Are you a tourist? Do you have a UK visa?

Comment: [The applicable UK rules are described here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travelling-between-the-uk-and-ireland-isle-of-man-guernsey-or-jersey) but they are really ambiguous. It seems to say everything is fine for most EEA nationals if no one asks to see a passport, but one might be in trouble if they do ask and you don't have one, so I guess the question of whether taking that ferry might prompt someone to ask for a passport is relevant.

Comment: @Dennis I believe that "Ireland" on that page refers to the republic, not the whole island.  This trip is from one part of the UK to another.

Comment: @Dimitar Slovov If you plan to travel by Stenaline, have you contacted them to ask about their ID rules?

Comment: @phoog, That's true, I was making the perhaps unwarranted assumption that the OP got to Belfast via the Republic, probably because I was remembering [this recent question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169636/can-bulgarian-citizen-travel-to-ireland-with-only-their-national-id-card/169653). I guess it is possible to have previously passed UK immigration but not currently be in possession of those documents, though.